# SQLite Prepared Statements not Inserting if bind text contains dash

Tags: sqlite, prepared-statement, bind

I run into the problem that a TEXT field of a TABLE cannot be bind to a string containing a dash. If i remove or replace the dash/dashes against any character the prepared and bind statement works fine.

Here two code fragments. The demo table is like "create table MyTable (SomeTime text)"

```
//do not work... runs into commit!! but add nothing to MyTable
int result = sqlite3_exec(validSqlite3, "begin;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    return;
sqlite3_stmt* stmt = nullptr;
bool ok = true;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(validSqlite3, "insert into MyTable (SomeTime) values (?);", -1, &stmt, nullptr) != SQLITE_OK)
    ok = false;
if (ok && sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "2016-11-01 12:00:00", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
    ok = false;
if (ok && sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
    ok = false;
if (ok && sqlite3_finalize(stmt) != SQLITE_OK)
    ok = false;
if (ok)
    sqlite3_exec(validSqlite3, "commit;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
else
    sqlite3_exec(validSqlite3, "rollback;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

//same code as above... BUT: no dashes in the text field    
//works fine... runs into commit and inserts a new row in MyTable with column SomeTime content: "2016/11/01 12:00:00"
int result = sqlite3_exec(validSqlite3, "begin;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    return;
sqlite3_stmt* stmt = nullptr;
bool ok = true;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(validSqlite3, "insert into MyTable (SomeTime) values (?);", -1, &stmt, nullptr) != SQLITE_OK)
    ok = false;
if (ok && sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "2016/11/01 12:00:00", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
    ok = false;
if (ok && sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
    ok = false;
if (ok && sqlite3_finalize(stmt) != SQLITE_OK)
    ok = false;
if (ok)
    sqlite3_exec(validSqlite3, "commit;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
else
    sqlite3_exec(validSqlite3, "rollback;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Comment: And what is the error message (`sqlite3_errmsg()`)?

Comment: Now i added between every line sqlite3_errmsg. After sqlite3_step == SQLITE_DONE i got "unknown error"...

I'm using Sqlite 3.15

Comment: But i got the "unknown error" errormsg in both cases after sqlite3_step. The commit results in SQLITE_OK too (in both cases) without any error hint.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that bind text containing dashes will not be inserted... Only if i uses prepare and bind.... A simple sqlite3_exec with text values containing dashes will be inserted. But why not with sqlite3_bind_text?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].